# Time needed to algebraically solve system of $15$ nonlinear equations with parameters

Tags: matlab, systems-of-equations, computational-mathematics

How long can I expect it will take to algebraically solve a system of $15$ nonlinear equations (without any numbers, only parameters), if I feed it into a computing software?

I'm asking for symbolic solving - is MAPLE, MATLAB, or Mathematica the best?

Here are the equations that I am talking about:

$$A - Ba - \frac{Va(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} - \frac{Wa(b+d)}{z} = 0$$

$$\frac{Wa(b+d)}{z} - \frac{Vb(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} - (B+D+GF)b = 0$$

$$\frac{Va(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} - \frac{Wc(b+d)}{z} - (B+E+C)c = 0$$

$$\frac{Vb(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} + \frac{Wc(b+d)}{z} - (B+C+D+F)d = 0$$

$$GFb - \frac{Ve(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} - (B+H)e = 0$$

$$He - \frac{Vf(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} - (B+S)f = 0$$

$$Sf - \frac{Vg(c+d+t+s+h)}{z}-Bg = 0$$

$$\frac{Vg(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} + Ss - (B+C+E)h = 0$$

$$Fd + \frac{Ve(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} - (B+C+H+T)t = 0$$

$$Ht + \frac{Vf(c+d+t+s+h)}{z} - (U+B+C+S+S)s = 0$$

$$Tt + \frac{W(b+d)x}{z} - (B+H+Y)u = 0$$

$$Us - (S+B)v + Hu - \frac{HvY}{H+S} = 0$$

$$S(s+v) - Bw + Zy+ Eh = 0$$

$$Ec - (\frac{W(b+d)}{z}+B)x = 0$$

$$Y(u + \frac{H}{H+S})v - (B+X)y- Zy = 0$$

**WHERE:**

$$z = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + s + t + u + v + w + x + y$$

**AND:**

$$ a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z > 0 $$

I hope someone can help, considering all the effort I have put in!! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anonymous; Could take a very long time or be done quickly, depends on the non-linear terms. Generally, I would say that is tough. What do the equations look like?

Comment: Hi bobbym, would you consider taking a look at my equations if I attach an image? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I have the time. Keep in mind though that symbolic solutions are much slower than numerical ones.

Comment: @bobbym Let me know if you need clarification, I can type them out shortly.

Comment: What did you think of Arnold's answer on the other forum? Sounds like good advice. I do not believe that anybody there solved the OP's question. Yours will be much tougher.

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect that there is a closed-form solution? That's quite exceptional for nonlinear ODEs.

Comment: @Hans I actually intend to solve this system with setting all the L.H.S. equal to 0. Then it becomes an algebraic system of nonlinear equations.

Comment: Suppose you have a system of $n$ equations in as many unknowns, of which $k$ are quadratic such as your equation (1) and $n-k$ are linear such as (15). Then under the best of circumstances one might be able to reduce this to a single polynomial equation of degree $2^k$ in one unknown. In your case, $k = 12$ so a polynomial equation of degree $2^{12} = 4096$ might be the result, for which there is surely no closed form solution. So this is not the right approach to take. If you want to analyze this problem, you might look at some limiting cases where many of the parameters are 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to analyze a population biology model of HIV and TB, and am trying to find the endemic equilibrium (state in which the diseases persist) - for which limiting cases would not make sense!

Comment: The first thing I would do is a substitution: $q = c + d + t + s + h$, since that sum appears so very often. But overall, I'd consider the problem pretty hopeless, as Hans has already suggested. Also: it looks as if your problem is homogeneous of degree two, so that if you have a solution, then any multiple of it is also a solution. That means you can normalize, and search only for solutions with (for example) $z = 1$; that has the advantage that it gets rid of almost all quotients.